# How to create UIButton action in custom class in Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, action, target

I want to create a class to add UIButton action, and then viewcontroller can call this class to create action.

But the error message told me "unrecognized selector sent to instance "

How can I fix them?

```
class MYController: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var pptMode: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var videoMode: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var meetingMode: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var videoMeeting: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ModeChange().modeChangeUtil(self,pptMode:pptMode, videoMode: videoMode, meetingMode: meetingMode, videoMeeting: videoMeeting)

    }
}


class ModeChange {

    func modeChangeUtil(vc:UIViewController,pptMode:UIButton,videoMode:UIButton,meetingMode:UIButton,videoMeeting:UIButton){
        pptMode.addTarget(vc, action: "modeTouched:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        pptMode.tag = modeButtonTag.ppt.rawValue

        videoMode.addTarget(vc, action: "modeTouched:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        videoMode.tag = modeButtonTag.video.rawValue
        meetingMode.addTarget(vc, action: "modeTouched:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        meetingMode.tag = modeButtonTag.meeting.rawValue
        videoMeeting.addTarget(vc, action:"modeTouched:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        videoMeeting.tag = modeButtonTag.videoMeeting.rawValue


    }
    enum modeButtonTag: Int {
        case ppt
        case video
        case meeting
        case videoMeeting
    }
   func modeTouched(sender:UIButton){
        let modeCmd:ModeCommand = ModeCommand(device: Mode(onoffUrl: OfficeConstants.MeetingRoom3A.MODE))
        switch sender.tag {
        case modeButtonTag.ppt.rawValue:
            modeCmd.modeStatus = .PPT

        case modeButtonTag.video.rawValue:
            modeCmd.modeStatus = .Video
        case modeButtonTag.meeting.rawValue:
            modeCmd.modeStatus = .Meeting
        case modeButtonTag.videoMeeting.rawValue:
            modeCmd.modeStatus = .VideoMeeting
        default: break
            //do nothing
        }
        modeCmd.execute()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have taken UIbutton action outlet in custom class then remove it..cz i had face same issue .

Answer (score 0):

You passed an incorrect parameter!

The `addTarget` method takes 3 parameters:

1. `target` is the instance to which the selector will be sent.
2. `action` is a selector
3. `forControlEvents` is the event that you want to handle

After explaining these, can you figure out which parameter is wrong in your code?

It's the `target`!

Since the selector will be sent to the `target`, the target must have a method called `modeTouched:`.

In your method call, you passed in `vc` as the `target`. This means that the selector `modeTouched:` must be sent to `vc`. However, you did not define a `modeTouched:` method in `vc`! That's why the error occurred.

I guess you want to send the selector to the `modeTouched:` method in the `ModeChange` class. Thus, the target should be `self`:

```
pptMode.addTarget(self, action: #selector(modeTouched:), forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

That should fix it!

Comment: I tried to use your suggetion code in swift2.
pptMode.addTarget(self, action:"modeTouched:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
But It doesn't work.

Comment: I tried another way,but still doesn't work.
pptMode.addTarget(self, action: #selector(modeTouched(_:)), forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
@objc func modeTouched(sender:UIButton){ }